# Thunderbird ignores locale

Tags: thunderbird, language-support, locale

I just added another user account to my 15.10 machine (Unity Desktop). My first account had an English locale set, which worked correctly everywhere:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The new account should have a German locale instead and is configured like this:

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

This works for all applications **except Thunderbird**. It still displays the entire GUI in English.

I have both `thunderbird` version 43 and the necessary locale package `thunderbird-locale-de` installed from `ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next`.

```
$ apt-cache policy thunderbird thunderbird-locale-de
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Candidate: 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:38.5.1+build2-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
thunderbird-locale-de:
  Installed: 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Candidate: 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:43.0~b1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:38.5.1+build2-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: If you go under Addon>Languages in Thunderbird, do you have the German package? Under System Settings>Language Support, is German the first language?

Comment: Have you tried to install the thunderbird and thunderbird-locale-de packages from the Ubuntu archive instead of that PPA?

Comment: @dadexix86 Thank you! It appeared in Add-ons/Languages, but was disabled there by default. After enabling it and restarting Thunderbird, the localization is correct. Would you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @byte-commander I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Thunderbird and navigate to the menu **<kbd>Tools</kbd>** → **<kbd>Add Ons</kbd>**, go to the **<kbd>Languages</kbd>** tab and make sure that you have **enabled** the German language package.